# Caption and footnote width with ctable

Tags: tables, captions, footnotes, ctable

I am using `ctable` and I have a table with footnotes. Since the table is narrow, the caption text is squeezed in the table width, which looks odd. I can use `mincapwidth` to specify a minimum width for the table environment (not the table itself) which solves this issue, but creates another: it also applies to the footnote, which looks ugly since the footnote is small. Is there a way to make the footnote obey the width of the table itself and ignore `mincapwidth`?

Example:

```
\ctable[
caption = {Somewhat long long long caption which is long},
mincapwidth = \textwidth,
]{lr}{
  \tnote[a]{Short footnote}
}{
    \toprule
    Header 1 & Header 2 \\
    \midrule
    foo\tmark[a] & 1 \\
    \bottomrule
}
```

Which looks like this

[image: End result]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a solution that adds a new key-value `footerwidth` (default is the width of the table):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ctable
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

\makeatletter
\newdimen\@ctblfooterwidth
\define@key{ctbl}{footerwidth}{\@ctblfooterwidth=#1}
\xpatchcmd{\ctable}% <cmd>
  {{\@ctblbeg}}% <search>
  {{\ifdim\@ctblfooterwidth=0pt
     \@ctblfooterwidth\@ctblw% or \@ctblfloatwidth for default as width of float
   \fi%
   \@ctblbeg}}% <replace> {\@defaultctblmincapwidth%
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\xpatchcmd{\ctable}{\hsize}{\@ctblfooterwidth}{}{}% Patch \ctable
\xpatchcmd{\ctable}{\hsize}{\@ctblfooterwidth}{}{}% Patch \ctable
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ctable[
caption = {Somewhat long long long caption which is long},
mincapwidth = \textwidth,
]{lr}{
  \tnote[a]{Short footnote}
}{
    \toprule
    Header 1 & Header 2 \\
    \midrule
    foo\tmark[a] & 1 \\
    \bottomrule
}

\ctable[
caption = {Somewhat long long long caption which is long},
mincapwidth = \textwidth,
footerwidth = .5\textwidth
]{lr}{
  \tnote[a]{Short footnote}
}{
    \toprule
    Header 1 & Header 2 \\
    \midrule
    foo\tmark[a] & 1 \\
    \bottomrule
}
\end{document}
```

[`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) provides the patch to `\ctable` since it takes an optional argument.

The first patch inserts the appropriate definition of the newly defined dimension `\@ctblfooterwidth` if it has no length. The second and third patch replaces the default `\hsize` width of the footnote encasing in either a `minipage` or `tabularx` environment, as defined within `\ctable` originally.

Answer (score 10):

I use, in this cases, a "poor man's `ctable`":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\@tabnotebox}
\providecommand\tmark{} % so having ctable or not is irrelevant
\providecommand\tnote{}
\newenvironment{tabularwithnotes}[3][c]
  {\long\def\@tabnotes{#3}%
   \renewcommand\tmark[1][a]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\textsuperscript{\itshape##1}}}%
   \renewcommand\tnote[2][a]{\textsuperscript{\itshape##1}\,##2\par}
   \begin{lrbox}{\@tabnotebox}
   \begin{tabular}{#2}}
  {\end{tabular}\end{lrbox}%
   \parbox{\wd\@tabnotebox}{
     \usebox{\@tabnotebox}\par
     \smallskip\@tabnotes
   }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Somewhat long long long caption which is long}
\medskip
\begin{tabularwithnotes}{lr}
 {
  \tnote[a]{Short footnote}
  \tnote[b]{Short footnote}
 }
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 \\
\midrule
foo\tmark[a] & 1\tmark[b] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularwithnotes}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The arguments to `tabularwithnotes` are the same as for `tabular`, with the notes in an additional argument.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Send a feature request – there should be an option to have the caption set outside the minipage which contains the table and notes. In the meantime, you can make this change yourself:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\modctable}[4][]{%
   \let\@ctbltaborfig  \@defaultctbltaborfig
   \let\@ctblalign     \@defaultctblalign
   \let\@ctblsideways  \@defaultctblsideways
   \let\@ctblcontinued \empty
   \let\@ctblpos       \@defaultctblpos
   \let\@ctblcaption   \empty
   \let\@ctblcap       \undefined
   \let\@ctbllabel     \empty
   \let\@ctblbotcap    \@defaultctblbotcap
   \let\@ctblstarred   \@defaultctblstarred
   \let\@ctblsuper     \@defaultctblsuper
   \let\@ctblnotespar  \@defaultctblnotespar
   \let\@ctbldoinside  \@defaultctbldoinside
   \@ctblframerule     \@defaultctblframerule
   \@ctblcaptionskip   \@defaultctblcaptionskip
   \@ctblframesep      \@defaultctblframesep
   \@ctblwidth         \@defaultctblwidth
   \@ctblmaxwidth      \@defaultctblmaxwidth
   \@ctblmincapwidth   \@defaultctblmincapwidth
   \def\@ctblfgactual {@defaultctblframefg}
   \def\@ctblbgactual {@defaultctblframebg}
   \def\@ctblbeg      {\begin{\@ctblsideways\@ctbltaborfig\@ctblstarred}}
   \def\@ctblbegin    {\@ctblbeg}
   \def\@ctblend      {\end{\@ctblsideways\@ctbltaborfig\@ctblstarred}}
   \setkeys{ctbl}{#1}
   \ifdim\@ctblwidth=0pt\else
      \ifdim\@ctblmaxwidth=0pt\else
         \PackageError{ctable}{
            You may not use the width and maxwidth options together}{
            Use either width or maxwidth}
      \fi
   \fi
   \ifx\@ctblpos\empty
      \ifx\@ctblsideways\empty\else
      \PackageError{ctable}{
         You may not use the pos and sideways options together}{
         Rotated tables and figures are always typeset on a separate page}
      \fi
   \fi
   \ifx\@ctblcaption\empty
      \ifx\@ctbllabel\empty\else
         \PackageError{ctable}{
            You may not label a captionless table}{
            Such a label can't be referenced}
      \fi
   \fi
   \sbox\ctbl@t{%
      \@ctblXcolumntype{l}% temporarily make  type X = l
      \@ctblframe{\@ctblfgactual}{\@ctblbgactual}{%
         \@ctbldoinside
         \begin{tabular}{#2}
            #4%
         \end{tabular}%
      }%
   }%
   \newif\if@ctblusex\@ctblusexfalse
   \ifdim\@ctblmaxwidth=0pt
      \ifdim\@ctblwidth=0pt
      \else
         \@ctblusextrue
      \fi
   \else
      \ifdim\wd\ctbl@t>\@ctblmaxwidth
         \@ctblusextrue
      \fi
   \fi
   \if@ctblusex
      \sbox\ctbl@t{%
         \@ctblXcolumntype{Y}% restore X
         \@ctblframe{\@ctblfgactual}{\@ctblbgactual}{%
            \@ctbldoinside
            \begin{tabularx}{\ifdim\@ctblwidth>0pt\@ctblwidth\else\@ctblmaxwidth\fi}{#2}
               #4%
            \end{tabularx}%
         }%
      }%
   \fi
   \@ctblw=\wd\ctbl@t
   \@ctblfloatwidth=\ifdim\@ctblmincapwidth>\@ctblw
      \@ctblmincapwidth
   \else
      \@ctblw
   \fi
   \@ctblbegin
      \ifx\@ctblcontinued\empty\else\addtocounter{\@ctbltaborfig}{-1}\fi
      \@ctblalign
      \@ctblCaption
      \begin{minipage}{\@ctblfloatwidth}\parindent0pt
         %%%%\ifx\@ctblbotcap\@ctblfalse\@ctblCaption\vskip\@ctblcaptionskip\fi
         \centering{\usebox\ctbl@t} % insert the tabular
         \def\@ctblfootnotes{#3}%
         \ifx#3\empty\else{% append footnotes, if any
            \footnotesize
            \ifx\@ctblnotespar\@ctbltrue%
               \\[.2ex]
               \begin{minipage}{\hsize}%
                  #3%
               \end{minipage}%
            \else%
               \\
               \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{r@{\,}>{\raggedright}X}
                  #3%
               \end{tabularx}%
            \fi

         }
         \fi
         %%%%\ifx\@ctblbotcap\@ctbltrue\vskip\@ctblcaptionskip\@ctblCaption\fi
      \end{minipage}
   \@ctblend
}
\makeatother
```

Then the command in-text becomes:

```
\modctable[
caption = {Somewhat long long long caption which is long},
]{lr}{
  \tnote[a]{Short footnote}
}{
    \toprule
    Header 1 & Header 2 \\
    \midrule
    foo\tmark[a] & 1 \\
    \bottomrule
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you should not use the booktabs commands explicitly, they are used internally, with modifications. Use \FL, \ML, \LL, see my sample text below.
Second: are you using ctable v1.21 or higher?

I suggest that I introduce an option footerwidth which:
- if absent changes nothing (obviously)
- if present without a value sets footnotes in the width of the tabular
- if present with a value, sets footnotes in the width of that value
Any better ideas?

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage[papersize={150mm,100mm},noheadfoot,margin=5mm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\ctable[
  caption = {Somewhat long caption, no footerwidth set},
  mincapwidth = \textwidth,
]{lr}{
  \tnote[a]{Short footnote}
}{\FL
  Header 1 & Header 2 \ML
  foo\tmark[a] & 1 \LL
}

\ctable[
  caption = {Somewhat long caption, footerwidth set, without a value},
  mincapwidth = \textwidth,
  footerwidth
]{lr}{
  \tnote[a]{Short footnote}
}{\FL
  Header 1 & Header 2 \ML
  foo\tmark[a] & 1 \LL
}

\ctable[
  caption = {Somewhat long caption, no footerwidth set to 15mm},
  mincapwidth = \textwidth,
  footerwidth = 15mm
]{lr}{
  \tnote[a]{Short footnote}
}{\FL
  Header 1 & Header 2 \ML
  foo\tmark[a] & 1 \LL
}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[End result http://wybo.xs4all.nl/ctable.png](http://wybo.xs4all.nl/ctable.png)

Comment: Your existing example does not contain a definition of the `footerwidth` key. Please add this definition to create a standalone document.

Comment: Yes, I'm using 1.21. I wasn't aware of \FL etc, thanks! The footerwidth option you have suggested would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked and answered, however such a question is still relevant today and due to updates in the [`ctable`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctable) package I thought I should add my contribution to this question for future visitors.

From [`ctable`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctable)`v1.26` onwards there's an option `footerwidth=..` where a width can be specified for the footer seperate to `mincapwidth`.

I should add that it works just like [Werner explaind in their answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51806/71115), such that it defaults to typsetting the footnotes to have the width of the table regardless of what `mincapwidth` says. This could also have an argument to give it a fixed width as you would do to `mincapwidth` and it acts independently of `mincapwidth`

Therefore your code would become:

```
\ctable[
caption = {Somewhat long long long caption which is long},
mincapwidth = \textwidth,
footerwidth
]{lr}{
  \tnote[a]{Short footnote}
}{
    \toprule
    Header 1 & Header 2 \\
    \midrule
    foo\tmark[a] & 1 \\
    \bottomrule
}
```

[image: The table after adding the <code>footerwidth</code> option]