# Setting width of RawCaption

Tags: captions, width, floatrow

I have posted a question [Different width for caption and floatfoot with floatrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64012/different-width-for-caption-and-floatfoot-with-floatrow) (which contains a MWE) regarding setting caption and `\floatfoot` width in the `floatrow` package, which was answered so wonderfully!  I was not sure if proper etiquette is to create a new question although related, so please feel free to let me know if I should have simply added this as a comment in the previous answer.

In any case, I was wondering what the best way to set a custom width of the caption is, with regards to the method used in the previous question.  I did some research and found [Caption and footnote width with ctable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51793/caption-and-footnote-width-with-ctable), but it seems to pertain specifically to the `ctable` package and environment.

So I was wondering what the best way to obtain a specific width for my caption in the first link would be.  I wasn't sure if something like `minipage` or such would be a proper solution, or what the best/most proper way to define the width would be.

Comment: Don't worry, follow-up questions are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `\parbox` of the desired width. For example, to get a width equal to 0.6 times the width of the text area you can say:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\parbox{.6\textwidth}{\RawCaption{\caption{Selected Interatomic Distances of Protons in $\beta$-Pinene Normal Lactone}\label{fig:noeDistances}}}\vskip1ex
\floatbox[{\captop}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
    {}
    {\includegraphics{nOeDistances}
    \floatfoot{\textsuperscript{1}All distances reported are in \si{\angstrom}.\\ \textsuperscript{2}Selected carbon numbering is given in cyan.}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, exactly the look I was going for.  Thank you.